# The strangest thing - no error but python scripts not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, development-environment

I have Python 3 installed and it used to work all fine but now when I run a file from the command line (Windows), nothing happens - no error and no output from the file. See an example below where I am printing something out but when I call the file, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: You probable run it as python-3.x. Usually two programs are installed `python` which is Python-2.x, and `python3`, which is Python-3.x

Comment: I only have python3 installed: https://imgur.com/a/ni3td.

Comment: If I try `python3`, i get this error: https://imgur.com/a/aHrqp

Comment: have to ask - did you save the file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am not able to run any file really that's what is most confusing. I have tried reinstalling python and also restarting

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Not under Windows.

Comment: you could try to run it like: `python guitest.py`. I think you trashed your .py file association.

Comment: Have you tried: `C:\Path\to\python.exe guitest.py`?

Comment: @NeilDey what programming environment are you using? OS? Terminal?

What happens if you just try running the `python` command? You should get an interactive shell to type Python commands. Does printing work in the interactive console?

Comment: Yes "python" works to enter the console. Printing on the console works fine.

Comment: @NeilDey what programming environment are you using? What is your operating system and terminal application? Can you also include the output of the command `chcp`?

Comment: @andrewgu I am using pycharm, WIndows 10 and Command Window. The output of `chcp` is https://imgur.com/a/JYJdU

Comment: What does `python --version` say?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have 2 versions of python installed on your machine. You will have to specify the path to your python 3 in your C: drive